# How to traverse a tree and group leaf nodes?

Tags: c#, tree

I have an investor/investee `Entity` class which can invest into other entities, these relationships are provided by the `Relationship` class.

```
public Entity
{
   public int Id;
   public string Region;  
}

public Relationship
{
   public int Id;
   public Entity Investor;
   public Entity Investee;
}
```

These are organized in a tree.
Using the example, "Entity A invests into Entity B and Entity C" like below:

- Entity A

  - Entity B
  - Entity C

This can also be viewed as a `Node` where a `Node` class may look like

```
public class Node
{
   public Entity Entity;
   public List<Node> Children; 
}
```

I want to be able to group leaf nodes via the `Region` property. Using our example above this would change our graph into an aggregate `Entity`.

- Entity A

  - Aggregate Entity

    - Entity B
    - Entity C

How would I traverse the tree graph to identify nodes that can be grouped by the `Region` property and group them accordingly?

Comment: traversing is as usual - recursive method. Are you saying, you want to group your `public List<Node> Children;` for display purposes? May be convert `List<Node>` to `Dictionary<string, List<Node>>`?

Comment: Yes @T.S. that is exactly what I am trying to do with my leaf nodes, although only some of them.

The problem that I am having trouble visualising is when the parent of the child node differs but they belong to the same group.

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  The `RelationShip` class might represent a node in a general directed graph, nothing prevents cycles or multiple "parents", so that is not a tree. So please, edit your question and clarify. Show us the real structure

Comment: *"when the parent of the child node differs but they belong to the same group"*... can you group by Region, then Parent? One of these has to be either subgroup, or switch modes - group by parent, group by region, group by parent then region

Comment: I really appreciate the time taken to answer my question; it's been a great help.

I problem I am having is using the following example:

A list of entities: A, B, C, D, E, F.

Using the above entities the relationships look like:

A -> B

A -> C

A -> F

B -> D

C -> D 

C -> E 

C -> F

And we would like to group D together by Region (say, United Kingdom) and then we would like to group E and F together (for example, United States).

Which would then give us the following entities

A 

B

C

United Kingdom (D)

United States (E, F)

How would we do this?